# Tkinter Label text doesn't change every time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Python 3.6.
This is a class i made for tkinter, where the text of `self.compteur` changes every second once i press start :

```
motsCount = 0
temps_total = 3600

class ChronoAspi:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.mainframe = tkinter.Frame(self.master, background ='#28aae1')
        self.mainframe.pack(fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand= True)
        self.timer_text = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.timer_text.trace('w', self.build_timer)
        self.time_left = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.time_left.set(temps_total)
        self.running = True
        self.buildGrid()
        self.build_buttons()
        self.build_timer()
        self.build_compteur()
        self.update()

    def buildGrid(self):
        self.mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(2, weight=0)

    def build_buttons(self):
        buttons_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.mainframe)
        buttons_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=10, pady=10)
        buttons_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        buttons_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.start_button = tkinter.Button(buttons_frame, text='Start', command=self.start_timer )
        self.stop_button = tkinter.Button(buttons_frame, text='Stop', command=self.stop_timer)
        self.start_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = 'ew')
        self.stop_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = 'ew')
        self.stop_button.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)

    def build_timer(self, *args):
        timer = tkinter.Label(self.mainframe, text=self.timer_text.get(), background = '#28aae1', fg='white', font=("Helvetica", 30))
        timer.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def build_compteur(self, *args):
        self.compteur = tkinter.Label(self.mainframe, text='Aucun mot compté.', background = '#28aae1', fg='white', font=("Helvetica", 20))
        self.compteur.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def start_timer(self):
        self.time_left.set(temps_total)
        self.running = True
        self.stop_button.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        self.start_button.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)

    def stop_timer(self):
        self.running = False
        self.stop_button.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        self.start_button.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)

    def heures_minutes_secondes(self, seconds):
        return int(seconds/3600), int(seconds%3600/60), int(seconds%60)

    def update(self):
        global motsCount
        time_left = self.time_left.get()

        if self.running and time_left:
            heure, minutes, seconds = self.heures_minutes_secondes(time_left)
            self.timer_text.set('{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}'.format(heure ,minutes, seconds) )
            self.time_left.set(time_left-1)
            motsCount += 1
        else:
            heure, minutes, seconds = self.heures_minutes_secondes(time_left)
            self.timer_text.set( '{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}'.format(heure ,minutes, seconds))
            self.compteur['text'] = 'Compteur stoppé.'
            self.stop_timer()

        if motsCount > 0:
            self.compteur['text'] = str(motsCount) + ' mots comptés.'

        self.master.after(1000, self.update)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    ChronoAspi(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

As long as the chronometer is running, the text of `self.compteur`changes every second. But when i hit the `self.stop_button`, `self.running` becomes `False` and the `else` part in the `update()` function is executed. So the chronometer stops but the `self.compteur` text doesn't change and I don't know why!

Comment: I tried running your code and got `IndentationError` on the `self.master.after` line. I tried indenting that line and I got `UnboundLocalError` on the `motsCount += 1` line. Please post code that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @Kevin sorry for that, i changed it, it was wrong copy paste for the post. The problem is solved btw, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I can't comment but I think your if statement is gonna run after self.stopTimer returns and gonna change the text back